# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'lgi' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a query that appears to work, doesn't throw an error.
I get an 'lgi' is undefined error when calling the value?

```
def search_staff():
    sql_staff = """SELECT s.forename, s.surname, s.brc, s.oou_id, s.staff_id, s.status, lgi.staff_id
                    FROM staff s
                        JOIN local_grant_investigators as lgi ON s.staff_id = lgi.staff_id
                    GROUP BY s.forename, s.surname, s.brc, s.oou_id, s.staff_id, s.status, lgi.staff_id;
    """
    r_s = list(conn.execute(text(sql_staff)))
```

```html
{% if staff %}
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Cluster</th>
        <th>TEST Cluster ID</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
        {% for s in staff %}                    
        <tr>                
        <td> {{ s.surname }} </td>
        <td> {{ s.forename }} </td>
        <td> {{ s.status }} </td>   
        <td> {{ s.staff_id }} </td>                                 
        <!-- <td>   -->             
          {% if s.staff_id %}          
        <td>
            {{ lgi.staff_id }}
        </td>
          {% endif %}                           
        <!-- </td>   -->                                
        <td>                 
        </td>                   
        <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#editstaff" class="staffedit" id="{{s.staff_id}}|{{s.forename}}|{{s.surname}}"> Edit </a></td>   
        <!--    <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#removestaff" class="staffremove" id="{{s.staff_id}}|{{s.forename}}|{{s.surname}}"> Remove </a></td>  -->   
        </tr>               
        {% endfor %}                        
        </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskClive\theapp\routes.py", line 1003, in search_staff
    return render_template('search_staff.html', staff=r_s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskClive\theapp\templates\search_staff.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskClive\theapp\templates\base.html", line 102, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FlaskClive\theapp\templates\search_staff.html", line 67, in block "content"
    {{ lgi.staff_id }}
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 430, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'lgi' is undefined
```

Comment: `lgi` isn't defined in your jinja template also your SQL query returns one set of results not two tables

Comment: Hi eagle9, I tried {% if s.staff_id == lgi.staff_id %}                                 Still get the error. Not sure what you mean it is not defined, it is referenced in staff??                                                                  
Doesn't the join return the two tables??

Comment: no, a join only returns one table, and you're looping through only one variable `for s in staff` so there is no notion of `lgi` in your template

Comment: Hi Eagle9, I added {% for lgi in staff %} before {% if s.staff_id == lgi.staff_id %}. That seemed to sort the problem. Thanks

Comment: you're doing another unecessary loop that way, please look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL query to this:

```
sql_staff = """SELECT s.forename, s.surname, s.brc, s.oou_id, s.staff_id, s.status, lgi.staff_id as lgi_staff_id
                    FROM staff s
                        JOIN local_grant_investigators as lgi ON s.staff_id = lgi.staff_id
                    GROUP BY s.forename, s.surname, s.brc, s.oou_id, s.staff_id, s.status, lgi.staff_id;
    """
```

Then in your template do this:

```
    {% for s in staff %}                    
    <tr>                
    <td> {{ s.surname }} </td>
    <td> {{ s.forename }} </td>
    <td> {{ s.status }} </td>   
    <td> {{ s.staff_id }} </td>                                 
    <!-- <td>   -->             
      {% if s.staff_id %}          
    <td>
        {{ s.lgi_staff_id }}
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I spent hours trying to sort it.